# PHP regular expression matching date

Tags: php, regex, date

What is the correct regular expression to use to validate a date like. 2009/10/22 or 2009/01/01 etc. Platform PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = '2009/10/22';

if ( preg_match('/^(?:(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2}))\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/', $date ) ) {

    echo $date , ' is a valid date format.';

} else {

    echo $date , ' is not a valid date format!';

}

?>
```

Also please make sure you use **checkdate()** function in addition to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('#^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}$#', $date)) {
 ...
}
```

This will only match a date, but you have to verify that the date is valid too, e.g. there's no such thing as February 31.

Comment: Thank you but there is a code matching dates such as 2009-11-12

Here is this code:
if( is_string($value) && preg_match('/^(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})( (\d{2}):(\d{2})(:(\d{2}))?)?$/', $value, $m) )

but i want to match 2009/11/12 for example. Here value is a date string

Comment: That's exactly what my code matches. You haven't even tried it, have you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this — validate the format first and then use `checkdate()` to validate the value:

```
$value = '2009/10/22';

echo valid_date($value) ? "Yep, $value is a valid date" : "Nah, it's not valid";

function valid_date($value)
{
    return preg_match('/^(?:(\d{4,})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}))$/', $value, $matches) === 1 && checkdate((int)$matches[2], (int)$matches[3], (int)$matches[1]);
}
```

Plain `preg_match()` just won't cut it.